# Cannot add foreign key constraint in phpmyadmin - mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have a table called `teachers`. I cannot use the `id` from `teachers` to create a composite table in `slot` table with  the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE `teachers` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

ALTER TABLE `teachers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `teachers_email_unique` (`email`);
```

to create slot table

```
CREATE TABLE `slot` (
  `teacher_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY kEY (`teacher_id`),
    foreign key (`teacher_id`) references `teachers`(`id`) on delete CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data type of the referencing and referenced fields, should be exactly the same while defining a Foreign Key constraint. In your `teachers` table, `id` is `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, while in your `slot` table, it is `BIGINT` only. Add `UNSIGNED` clause as well:

```
CREATE TABLE `slot` (
  `teacher_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `is_confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY kEY (`teacher_id`),
    foreign key (`teacher_id`) references `teachers`(`id`) on delete CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```